# By How many Percent Do I have to move Line to get 45 degree

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

How do I calculate the value of `Y` that will make the angle 45 deg. The side (Y+Z) is calculated in percentage, so that Y is said to be x% of the length (Y+Z).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 1):

If the grey shape is a square, then you only need note that $\tan45=1=\frac{y}{\text{base}}$ to establish that $y=\text{base}\to x=100\%$.